# How to dynamically create a table from a JSON with nested lists using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table, nested-lists

I'm trying to create an HTML table from a JSON file which values can include nested lists.

Example:

```
{
     "entry 1":[
         ["text1", "text2", "text3"],
         ["text4", "text5", "text6"],
         ["text7", "text8", "text9"]
    ],
    "entry 2": "N/A",
    "entry 3": [
         ["text1", "text2", "text3"],
         ["text4", "text5", "text6"]
    ],
    "entry 4": [
         ["text1", "text2"],
         ["text3", "text4"]
    ]
}
```

My goal is to create an HTML table with a predefined header for the two columns:

- `header_title_1`
- `header_title_2`

That will never change, and the table should look like this:

[image: table_example]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Stack overflow is not a free code writing service; have you tried anything so far?

Comment: `Object.keys(obj)` gives keys which can be iterated over to get desired table HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `for...in` iterator on the object to get the `key`. I created a row for each property, then a cell for the key and value. Then if the value isn't an array, like the `entry2` key, we make it an array to iterate through the elements.

Creating a new row for each element in the array and creating a new cell for the items in the array. If it is an array, the value would be converted to a string separated by the comma ',' or it would be set just as it is.

Then we append the elements to the body of the table.

```js
const tbody = document.getElementById('table').tBodies[0];
const obj = {"entry 1":[["text1","text2","text3"],["text4","text5","text6"],["text7","text8","text9"]],"entry 2":"N/A","entry 3":[["text1","text2","text3"],["text4","text5","text6"]],"entry 4":[["text1","text2"],["text3","text4"]]};

function createTable(obj) {
  tbody.innerHTML = ''; // To reset the table
  
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    const value = Array.isArray(obj[key]) ? obj[key] : [obj[key]];
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    const key_cell = Object.assign(document.createElement('td'), {
      innerText: key
    });
    const value_column = Object.assign(document.createElement('td'), {
      innerText: value.splice(0, 1)[0]
    });

    row.append(...[key_cell, value_column]);
    tbody.append(row);

    value.forEach(val => {
      const inner_row = document.createElement('tr');
      const empty_key_cell = document.createElement('td');
      const value_cell = Object.assign(document.createElement('td'), {
        innerText: val
      });
      inner_row.append(...[empty_key_cell, value_cell]);
      tbody.append(inner_row);
    });
  }
}

createTable(obj);
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <td>header_title_1</td>
    <td>header_title_2</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works perfectly! If I want to add a horizontal line in between each row, should this be added in the JS script or the html ?

Comment: If you mean the way it looks like in the picture you linked, I've edited my code for that...

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: one last question, my page starts with filter buttons to select the JSON file to load before creating the table, should your script include a 'id = table' somewhere to make it dynamic ?

Comment: The first table loads just fine, but when I try to press the btton to load another JSON, I get the following error message in the console: "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive"

Comment: That is because you're passing the `passive` option while adding the [`eventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: I have edited my answer to use a function and the id to make it more `dynamic`

Answer (score 1):

Or, in a very short way, you could do the following instead:

```js
const obj=
{"entry 1":[["text1","text2","text3"],["text4","text5","text6"],["text7","text8","text9"]],
 "entry 2":"N/A",
 "entry 3":[["text1","text2","text3"],["text4","text5","text6"]],
 "entry 4":[["text1","text2"],["text3","text4"]]};
 
document.querySelector("#table tbody").innerHTML=
Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v])=>
   "<tr><td>"+k+"</td><td>"
  +(Array.isArray(v)?v:[[v]]).join("<hr>")
  +"</td></tr>").join("\n")
```

```css
td>hr {margin:0px}
td {vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <th>header_title_1</th>
    <th>header_title_2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```